# What the type URI on audio from local storage

Tags: plugins

LY, i need uri type for put audio files to video editor. I can't find uri type because you don't have documentation about it!

It's little example!

```
editVideo(video) {
    const config = {
        audio: {
          categories: [
            {
              items: [
                { audioURI: 'URI TYPE?' }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      };
    VESDK.openEditor(
      (args: any) => {
        console.log("SUCCESS ARGS", args)
      },
      (error: any) => {
        console.log("FAIL ERROR", error)
      },
      video.mobile_video_link,
      config
    );
  }
```

Frameworks: Ionic 6.0.0, Angular 13.0.0
Plugin: "cordova-plugin-videoeditorsdk": "^3.3.0"

I tried this example https://github.com/imgly/vesdk-ionic-demo but i didn't find information about audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `audioURI` should be a local file path. If you are using audio files that are contained in your application bundle (your resource folder) and not the local device storage, you will need to use the `PESDK.resolveStaticResource` method. This method resolves static resources that are shipped with your application so that they can be used by the native systems. If you are using any other local path you can just insert a valid path.

Please note that [remote resources are not optimized](https://github.com/imgly/vesdk-cordova/blob/master/types/configuration.ts#L1485) and therefore should be downloaded in advance and then passed as a local resource.